# Place a Microsoft Access hyperlink address from a neighboring cell

Tags: ms-access, hyperlink, macros

I need your help.

There is a table Microsoft Access.
In one kollonke - text. (ex. Simple Text)
In the other - the address where the line should be invoked. (ex. http://blablabla)

It is necessary to somehow automate the process. And make one kollonke text with a hyperlink from the second. (hiperlynk Simple text with link to http://blablabla)

Comment: Could you please be more specific?

Comment: Here is my database. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6523907/%D0%A1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA.JPG
I need to make in the "Адреса" text becomes a hyperlink to the address of the "Поле 2"